# Unable to create 108 dots in a circle

Tags: swift, uilabel

I am trying to create 108 dots in a circle and I am getting Index out of range error. The dots are created using an array of UILabels.

I have the following code:

```
func createMala() {
        let malaFrame = UIView()
        malaFrame.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width - 20, height: view.frame.width - 20)
        malaFrame.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width / 2.0, y: (malaFrame.frame.height / 2.0) + 20)

        var malaBeadLabel = [RoundLabel]()
        let malaRadius : Double = 100.0
        let angleInRadians : Double = 3.3333 * .pi / 180.0

        for i in 1...108 {
            malaBeadLabel[i].frame = CGRect(x: (malaRadius * sin(angleInRadians) * Double(i)),
                                            y: (malaRadius * cos(angleInRadians) * Double(i)),
                                            width: 2.0, height: 2.0)

            malaBeadLabel[i].layer.cornerRadius = 1.0
            malaBeadLabel[i].layer.borderWidth = 0.25
            malaBeadLabel.append(malaBeadLabel[i])

            malaFrame.addSubview(malaBeadLabel[i])
        }
    }
```

I cannot figure out how is the index out of range.

Comment: Your `malaBeadLabel` array is empty so there's nothing to access.

Comment: But I have the second last line where I am appending to the array in for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. I added the UIBezier path radius to both x and y coordinates of the UILabels around the circle and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You start with an empty array named `malaBeadLabel`.

Then during the first iteration of the loop, when `i` is 1, you try `malaBeadLabel[i]`. This of course causes the error because `malaBeadLabel` is empty and there is nothing at index 1 (or 0, or any other index).

On top of that, you never actually attempt to create any instances of `RoundLabel`.

Change your loop code so you make no attempt to access anything from the array, just add to the array. And create the actual label instances.

```
for i in 1...108 {
    let label = RoundLabel(frame: CGRect(x: (malaRadius * cos(angleInRadians * Double(i))),
                                    y: (malaRadius * sin(angleInRadians * Double(i))),
                                    width: 2.0, height: 2.0))

    label.layer.cornerRadius = 1.0
    label.layer.borderWidth = 0.25
    malaBeadLabel.append(label)

    malaFrame.addSubview(label)
}
```

BTW - why isn't the code to set the label's corner radius and border width inside the `RoundLabel` class?

Comment: Thanks. I think I realized 2 problems. One starting array with 1 and second not creating label instance. The reason why I am creating the label array is that later in the code I will use this array to change the color of round labels to white, indicating the progress for the user. But your two great points are going to help me. Let me give a shot. Also I am using round label class for other labels too. So I did not set corner radius and border width since all round label will have different radius values.

Comment: I tried it but didn’t work. I believe the code is correct. All I need to figure out is how to place the round labels from a center point at a certain radius. Do you know how?

Comment: I hadn't looked at the frame calculations originally but I just updated my answer to fix those. You need to multiply the angle by `i` before doing `sin` or `cos` and you had them backwards. `cos` is used for `x` and `sin` is for `y`.

Comment: Oh ok. But how do Xcode knows to place each label at the radius value from the malaFrame center?

Comment: Xcode doesn't know anything. The code you write to set the label's frame tells the view where to be. The updated code in my answer fixes your frame calculation.

Comment: Agree. But Xcode needs to know the CGPoint from where it is starting to calculate the radius value. basically how does it know the origin reference point of the radius.

Comment: Xcode is just the editor. It doesn't need to know anything. Don't confuse the editor you are using with the code and frameworks that actually run your app. It is the iOS framework UIKit and its classes such as `UIView` that need to know where the views go. The code in my answer creates a view with a given frame. That frame has an origin and a size. A view's frame is relative to the bounds of its parent view.

Comment: My previous comment made me realize that you will only see one quarter of the points because the rest will be either above or to the left of the parent view and therefore probably not visible. So you want to set the origin of each of these `RoundLabels` to be relative to the center of the their parent view, not the top-left corner of their parent view.

Comment: you are correct because circle has 4 quadrants but actually I am not able to see anything when I run on the simulator. see my image what I am trying to achieve.